# How to reuse Excel workbooks?

Tags: excel, spreadsheet

#### The setting

I make models in Excel. The overall structure is fairly simple, although the models may include several sheets:

```
WORKBOOK      _____________________________
             |                             |
Parameters --|--------------------\        |
             |                    V        |
             |  Constants -> Computations -|-> Results
             |_____________________________|
                         MODEL
```

where

- Parameters: variable values adjusted to fit to some business decisions
- Constants: definitory values of the model.
- Computations: feeds from Constants and Parameters, and are used to make calculations. This section might be several sheets, with interlinked values cells, complex functions. **This is the part that I want to reuse**
- Results: what business want to see, feeds from computations.

Business usually wants several different sets parameters, and being able to view the results for all this sets of parameters. The Model (*Constants* and *Computations*) would be the same for all the sets of parameters.

#### The issue

The customary solution for this is to design the Model, make $n$ copies of the WorkBook, feed the different sheets with the different parameters and collect, a.k.a copy paste, the results somewhere (1st flag) else, usually a $n+1$ WorkBook.

The problem comes when the Model has to be modified, let it be the Constants or Computations, or even more derived results are desired, the changes have to be propagated to the $n$ workbooks and pray that the ol' Ctrl-C,V does not break anything, and is done in the same cells.

#### What I need?

What I desire is a way to factor the Model into a some sort of "master" workbook or set of sheets in a book, and other workbooks to be able to reference the functions, and if posible the whole process, not the cells, to reuse the computations for each set of parameters, to get the corresponding results.

I've tried to use VBA to factor out the model sheets, but this means that I have to transform the sheets into VBA code, and takes away the flexibility that the Excel sheets gives, and might break when sharing with business, it ends to give a more fragile solution than copy/paste.

This models usually are not reused outside than for the task that they are made.

Comment: Perhaps you should check out the use of Templates - an option when you do "Saveas"

Comment: @SolarMike, I don't believe that would help, as If I change then the "master" workbook from where the template derives the workbooks done from the templates will not change.

Comment: I have roughly the same question, and have for years. I'm amazed you have received no replies; it seems like a fundamental question about best practice. Anyone building reasonably sophisticated systems of spreadsheets would benefit, especially those who are also programmers and are therefore used to having access to code libraries. Fingers crossed!

Comment: Incidentally, [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/90920/343537) suggests that for Excel questions, SuperUser might give better results than StackOverflow. Maybe try moving or at least re-posting your question to [SuperUser](https://superuser.com)?

Comment: Thanks @tkp, I will cross post it there. Yes, it seems a so basic functionality, coming from text programming, that it makes no sense there is not a easy way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

I already commented that I have had the same question myself, so what follows is an answer from someone who has not figured it out yet. However, prompted once more by your question into answer-hunting, I had another look and here is my opinion. (In all of this, assume it is liberally sprinkled with caveats such as, "as far as I can make out", "in my opinion", and "correct me, please, if I'm wrong")

### TL;DR

Since you are sharing both data and "code", your best bet is to package up your models into Excel Add-Ins.

### DETAILS

#### Sharing data only

When it comes to data--e.g. your *Parameters* and *Constants*--although there are several option, by far the easiest solution is to simply **keep the shared data in one or more shared workbooks that are then externally referenced** from the workbooks needing that data. Something like:

```
='[SharedWorkbook1.xlsx]SheetName1'!A1
```

In fact that--only data being reused--is my own use case, and I have indeed used that shared file approach in the past. However over time I began to avoid it because it seemed too brittle. If a shared file moved, or a Sheetname got changed, then the links would break and need repairing. However, now that I see that there is nothing more sophisticated (while being as easy) than the shared file approach, I reckon that the solution is simply to impose on myself (and any collaborators if needed) some conventions when it comes to location, naming, etc of shared workbooks.

**ADDED:** The shared-file-accessed-via-external-references method appears to have some frustrating restrictions if the share file is not open, depending on exactly how you use the external references. For example, accessing the shared data via something like INDEX() may not be possible for a closed shared file, unless the link is referencing a named range. In this case, for sufficiently modern Excel versions, PowerQuery may be a useful alternative.

#### Sharing "code"

However, the above approach of simple shared workbooks and external references works only for shared *data*, not for shared "*code*"--e.g. your *Computations*. So, for example, suppose in your shared workbook you have created a lambda function or some VBA: that kind of thing is *not* reusable from another sheet using an external reference. Same goes for regular in-cell formulae (I'm not sure about Macros though). **For this kind of "code" reuse, the simplest method is the [Excel Add-In](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-overview)**.

Comment: The Excel Add-In would have similar problems to the VBA, having to distribute something other than the Excels. And install.

But thanks for the research!